# cmake subdirectories install

Tags: cmake, installation, subdirectory

I would like to set up a new project using CMake.

My working dir is the following :

```
CMakeLists.txt
include
   - file1.h
src
   - file1.cpp
   - CMakeLists.txt
tests
   - test1.cpp
   - CMakeLists.txt
```

The main CMakeList.txt is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(bench CXX)
include_directories(include)
subdirs(src tests)
```

The src CMakeList.txt is :

```
add_library(foo SHARED file1.cpp)
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION lib)
```

And the tests CMakeList.txt is:

```
add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 foo)
install(TARGETS test1 DESTINATION bin)
```

I would expect the files to be located in

```
<build_dir>/bin/test1
<build_dir>/lib/libfoo.so
```

But instead they are organized like this :

```
<build_dir>/src/test1
<build_dir>/tests/libfoo.so
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You are giving instructions for the *install* step/build target, which is  independent from the build tree under `<binary_dir>`.
Set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to a folder of your choice and run `make install` (assuming make build system here) after your build. The you will find `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/lib/libfoo.so` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/bin/test1` as you told cmake. The `DESTINATION` path is always relative to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` (unless you specify an absolute path, of course).

The compiled libs and binaries within the build tree (i.e. `<build_dir>`) will always reflect the source tree structure with respect to location; this cannot be changed and is not the intended way of use.
Generally there are three different "things": Source/Build/Install trees. The build tree mirrors the source tree structure and contains cmake-generated extra files and objects. The install "tree" is a setting of your choice, where `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is the root directory under which libraries, archives and binaries are placed. You can control the behaviour completely (what you already intend to do!), although there are reasonable default settings.